# Display a specific viewcontroller on a TV with an ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, multiple-monitors

I need to know if it's possible to display one viewcontroller on a TV screen and another viewcontroller on the iPad simultaneously with a cable.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not, you can reproduce what's on your phone screen in a TV with the adapter, but nothing complex like that.

It's not even supported by iOS to have those 2 view controllers working in parallel